# Setting types in RN with TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

In my RN application, I have the following interface.

```
interface IProps extends Props<IProps> {
  label?: string;
  editable?: boolean;
  maxLength?: number;
  autoCorrect?: boolean;
  placeholder?: string;
  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  autoCapitalize?: 'none' | 'sentences' | 'words' | 'characters' | undefined;
  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  returnKeyType?: 'none' | 'done' | 'search' | 'default' | 'go' | 'next' | 'send' | 'previous' | 'google' | 'join' | 'route' | 'yahoo' | 'emergency-call';
  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  keyboardType?: 'default' | 'email-address' | 'numeric' | 'phone-pad' | 'visible-password' | 'ascii-capable' | 'numbers-and-punctuation' | 'url' | 'number-pad' | 'name-phone-pad' | 'decimal-pad' | 'twitter' | 'web-search' | undefined;
  secureTextEntry?: boolean;
  inputStyle?: object;
  containerStyle?: object;
  inputContainerStyle?: object;
}
```

Here the autoCapitalize, returnKeyType the type is an enum. It seems ugly to define the whole enum here. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
enum AutoCapitalize {
  NONE = 'none',
  SENTENCES = 'sentences',
  WORDS = 'words',
  CHARACTERS = 'characters',
  UNDEFINED = '',
}

enum ReturnKeyType {
  ...
}

interface IProps extends Props<IProps> {
  label?: string;
  editable?: boolean;
  maxLength?: number;
  autoCorrect?: boolean;
  placeholder?: string;
  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  autoCapitalize?: AutoCapitalize;
  ...
}
```

Comment: A `type` would be another good option here. enums are nice but you have to use them when passing a value or the type checking complains

Comment: A `type`? Wouldn't that make more sense in case of nested data-models and not if the values were primitives?

Comment: It depends on usage, `<Input autoCorrect={AutoCapitalize.SENTENCES}` vs `<Input autoCorrect="sentences"` for DOM attributes and things related to that (like `<Input type="text"` I would probably just use a type and string property personally. Just a preference :) +1 regardless